# PDFBox cannot find correct fallback font for cid-keyed font

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

In our company we're creating pdfs with tcpdf. Those pdfs will be downloaded and printed from a java application which uses latest pdfbox.

Normally they will be printed without a problem but sometimes we have documents with Chinese/Japanese characters in it.

For those characters the font(-type) [cid0ct](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/fonts/cid0ct.php) will be used.

If I open such a pdf in a pdf viewer there is no problem viewing it. Native windows, native macOS, Chrome pdf viewer, all fine.

If I try to print (or convert to image) such a pdf I only get some warnings because of using fallback font but it always uses a wrong font so there are many missing glyphs.

Command line command for converting:

```
java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.12.jar PDFToImage invoice_1001606.pdf
```

Result (shortened):

```
Okt 17, 2018 10:29:59 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType0 <init>
WARNUNG: Using fallback BrushScriptMT for CID-keyed font cid0ct
Okt 17, 2018 10:29:59 AM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.CIDType0Glyph2D getPathForCharacterCode
WARNUNG: No glyph for 20013 (CID 0295) in font cid0ct
Okt 17, 2018 10:29:59 AM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.CIDType0Glyph2D getPathForCharacterCode
WARNUNG: No glyph for 38920 (CID 0db2) in font cid0ct
Okt 17, 2018 10:29:59 AM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.CIDType0Glyph2D getPathForCharacterCode
```

I installed the complete [google fonts](https://github.com/google/fonts) package for testing but pdfbox only selects a wrong font again:

```
Okt 18, 2018 8:09:19 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType0 <init>
WARNUNG: Using fallback Jua-Regular for CID-keyed font cid0ct
```

Embedding the font into pdf is no option because we (or our customers) are generating thousands of documents each day and it will increase the size of pdfs.

I created an example pdf with some Chinese/Japanese characters in it:
[Google Drive - invoice_12.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CAbPpoELE9UAEhkLEfQaqd144LejP3pd/view?usp=sharing)

This is how the pdf looks like in chrome:
[image: Original pdf in chrome pdf viewer]

This is how the image looks like after converting it:
[image: Converted image]

Maybe you have some ideas how to set the/a correct fallback font or you know the correct font to use/install.

The only idea I have is to add a custom font to tcpdf which I can install on my operating system, too.

Comment: *"Embedding the font into pdf is no option because we (or our customers) are generating thousands of documents each day and it will increase the size of pdfs."* - If you really want to keep the size of the PDF small, why do you embed an unnecessarily large subset of FreeMonoBoldOblique? You only use the digits from it but you embed a subset containing at least all Latin1 glyphs so that the embedded font program requires 54 KB (29 KB compressed). If you cut that down to only the digits, you can easily also embed a subset of cid0ct containing the few used glyphs and end up with a smaller pdf...

Comment: That being said, you have issues with other glyphs, too, in Adobe Reader the umlauts, for example, are broken in different ways: 'ä' in "Währung" is missing, the dots of 'ü' in "Bürostuhl" are not above the 'u' but next to it, and the 'ü' in "für" looks like it's from a different font altogether. This clearly contradicts your claim "If I open such a pdf in a pdf viewer there is no problem viewing it."

Comment: I'm not the coder of the php part. Thanks for the hint with the embedded subset. I will look into it and will tell my co-worker about it.
Edit: The template with FreeMono is only an example template. None of our customers is using it.

Comment: As of tcpdf documentation, you cannot embed CID-0 fonts >.>
"The fonts that could be not embedded are only the standard core fonts and CID-0 fonts." https://tcpdf.org/docs/fonts/

Comment: I get "Using fallback ArialUnicodeMS for CID-keyed font cid0ct" but the "ä" of "Währung" doesn't appear properly. If you're not embedding your fonts, you're asking for trouble. Either embed your fonts, or use font names of which you know that they are installed on your recipients computers.

Comment: *"use font names of which you know that they are installed on your recipients computers."* - likely candidates would be the CJK fonts Adobe provides (IIRC as separate downloads) as Adobe Reader add-on.

Comment: You could get rid of the FreeMonoBoldOblique font by using Courier-BoldOblique which is a standard 14 font (like the Helvetica that you are using), i.e. works fine without embedding. Or get rid of these line numbers, they might confuse the automatic invoice processors of some of your clients.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, as I already mentioned those line numbers are only examples/templates. Customers will add their own templates without this stuff. I think we will add some new fonts to tcpdf for better support.

Comment: I tested with PDFBOX 2.0.14 on Windows 11 and the above issue occurs.  I tested with PDFBOX 2.0.25 on Windows 11 and the above issue does NOT occur.